Geometry Nodes Editor Panels default behaviour (4.1)
Is it possible to set the default behaviour for Blender's (4.1) Geometry Nodes editor so that panels stay closed in the editor, under the "Group" tab?
Every time I edit a custom node group within the main node group and then exit that group and go back up a level to the main node tree, then blam! All the panels are wide open again.
Same thing if I click onto another object in the outliner and then come back to the previous object and node tree I was working on.
It seems that Blender's default setting is for the panels to be open and the tick box for "Closed by Default" applies to the modifier's tab behaviour but not to the node editor workspace.

